# Is it possible to know the equation of a line by only knowing the slope and where the line intercepts the x axis?

Tags: graphing-functions, coordinate-systems

I do not know where my line intercepts the $y-$axis.
I know it intercepts the x axis at coordinate $(10, 0)$.
At an angle of $30^{\circ}$.

So would 
$$y = mx + b = (10\tan(30)) + b$$

be correct?  How do I find where my line intersects the $y-$axis and find the equation for this line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$m=\tan(30^\circ)$Then you know that $(10,0)$ is on the line, so $10 \tan(30^\circ)+b=0$, or $b=-10\tan(30^\circ)$. Therefore the equation of the line is $$y=\tan(30^\circ)(x-10)$$

Comment: Sorry, i think I'm failing at understanding this, as in I now understand how you got b=... thanks for that but I'm not sure how you got to the final equation.

Comment: You have your equation $y=mx+b$, and you already found $m=\tan(30^\circ)$. But you don't know $b$.  Now what does that equation mean? It means that any point on that line obey that equation. In particular, you know that at $x=10$ you have $y=0$. So you plug in those values $0=m\cdot 10+b$, which means $b=-10m$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

If you know the slope $m$ and *any point* $(x_0,y_0)$ on the line, then by solving

$$y_0=mx_0+p,$$ you get $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation $$y = mx + b = (10\tan(30)) + b$$ is not correct.

Note that the slope of the line is $\tan(30)$ and you have the point $(10,0)$ on the line.

Thus the equation of the line is $$y-0=(\tan(30))(x-10)$$ which simplifies to $$ y = (\frac {\sqrt 3}{3})(x-10)$$

Comment: Could you explain how exactly you get to y−0=(tan(30))(x−10), I understand  = - (tan (30) * 10) because mx = (tan (30) * 10) + b. But then how does one form that equation y−0=(tan(30))(x−10) from these. should it not be y = (tan(30) * 10) + (- tan(30) * 10) - I know these will cancel each other out but y=mx + b makes it seem that way but I want to know how to form y−0=(tan(30))(x−10)

Comment: This is called point slope formula of a line.  The equation is $y-y_0 = m(x-x_0)$ where  $m$ is the slope and $(x_0, y_0)$ is a given point on the line. In your question, $m= \tan (30)$ and point is $(10,0)$

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you’re familiar with the slope-intercept form of the equation $y=mx+b$. For $m=0$, there’s an equivalent form that uses the reciprocal of the slope and $x$-intercept $c$: $x=\frac1m y+c$. You should convince yourself that this is correct by converting it to the more familiar slope-intercept form.